# How can I get the return value when backgroundworker is complete

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

I want to use this method:

```
public static bool SynchronizeFiles(string source, string destination)
```

in `BackgroundWorker`. I define `BackgroundWorker` and add it in `workerList`. Than do this work one by one.

```
private void CopyIfIsReady(Save save)
{
    if (save.isDriveReady && save.isFileChanged && save.isPeriodCompleted)
    {
        BackgroundWorker BW = new BackgroundWorker();
        BW.DoWork += (obj, e) => backgroundWorker1_DoWork(save);
        BW.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
        workerList.Add(BW);
        BW_timer.Start(500);
    }
}

private void BWTimerCallBack(object state)
{
    if (workerList.Count >= 0)
    {
        if(!workerList[0].IsBusy)
        {
            workerList[0].RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        BW_timer.Stop();
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(Save save)
{
    SynchronizeFiles(save.sourceFolder, save.destFolder);
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     workerList.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

But how can I take return value of `SynchronizeFiles` in `backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted`.

Comment: You should use `Task` and `await` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` method since it's only wrapping the `SynchronizeFiles` method call. You can change the event handler the following way:

```
BW.DoWork += (obj, e) => { e.Result = SynchronizeFiles(save.sourceFolder, save.destFolder); }
```

Now inside `backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted` you can access the result via the `e.Result` property.